# AC voltage at the output of SMPS

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

We have 230 VAC power supply in our lab.A chemical earthing is done for this power supply. I have connected a SMPS (LRS-35-12) to it. The Output of SMPS is connected to a load of maximum 2A. I have measured the smps output voltage as 12VDC and the device (load) is working and controller is sending data also. But at the same time I have turn my multi-meter at AC voltage mode and measured the SMPS output voltage,I found it as 25VAC. (I expected it to be around 0 VAC.)

So, what could be the reason of it?

Comment: What is "chemical earthing?"

Comment: It is basically the GI earthing( Rod earthing). Only we have added salt and charcoal around the rod to improve the earth pit resistance.

Comment: 25VAC across the SMPS outputs, or between the SMPS and earth?

Comment: I am giving the details below: Voltage between Line and neutral= 228-238VAC.   Voltage between Earth and neutral= 20-25 VAC.  Voltage at SMPS Output= 12VDC   Voltage at SMPS Output= 25VAC

Comment: So, as we have earthing so a 20-25VAC between earth and neutral is unexpected. Also it is unexpected to have 25VAC at the SMPS  output.

Comment: 25VAC between where and where? It's quite normal to see 25VAC between either DC output terminal and earth. But not between the two DC output terminals.

Comment: @Andy aka, I am worried about this only. I have found 25VAC between the two DC output terminal. Is it due to the reason a 20-25 VAC is coming between earth and neutral at the input side of SMPS ?

Comment: It's probably a red herring. Try connecting your multimeter across a 9 volt battery and see what the supposed AC voltage is.

Comment: Ya, it is 0.5 VAC when measured across a 12V Li-ion battery. I don't think it is a problem of multi-meter. Is it there any problem possible in the high frequency MOSFET inside the SMPS or in the filter circuit of it? But note that the output of smps is measured as 12VDC as expected.

Comment: @ Andy aka, Ok I got it. with the multi-meter by which i got 0.5VAC on 12V Li-ion battery, I measured the DC terminal voltage as 0.026 VAC. But, with the multi-meter by which i got 25VAC on smps output, i have found 16VAC on 12V Li-ion battery terminal. But, both the multi-meters are measuring DC voltage accurately. So, i don't think that one of the multi-meter is faulty. But why that multi-meter is measuring 25VAC instead of 0.026VAC in the smps output terminal?

Comment: if meter measures 16VAC in AC mode across 12V battery then DC offset introduce huge amount of error into AC voltage measurment, so 25VAC measurment across PSU DC output is not valid (outher AC voltages measured by that multimeter may also be invalid)